# Houdini change position based on last frame position

Tags: houdini, vex

I am trying to procedurally animate things in Houdini, using similar logic as in Unity, moving the object based on its current position, i.e., `NewPosition = OldPosition + Direction * Coefficient`.

Using the Vex code below inspired by [this post](https://www.sidefx.com/forum/topic/49259/):

```
vector @posRecord[];
// ... 
if (@Frame == 1)
{
    @P = {0, 0, 0};
}
else
{
    vector lastPos = @posRecord[len(@posRecord) - 1]; 
    v@lastRead = lastPos; 
    @P = lastPos + @N * 10; // @N as direction 
}

append(@posRecord, @P);
if (len(@posRecord) > 10)
    removeindex(@posRecord, 0);
```

I am able to record the position, but `lastPos` cannot properly read from `@posRecord`. In Geometry Spreadsheet `lastPos` keeps being 0. As a result, the object is merely reading the `@N` as XYZ positions instead of move based on `@N`.

What is going and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You're trying to read the last position from `@posRecord` and then append the new position to it. But, the append operation might be happening before the last position is read.

Comment: In what kind of node are you running this VEX code ? If it's a SOP Wrangle indeed you have to chance since it's computed from zero on each frame, so the posRecord list will never grow. If you are using a solver you are already in a context where you can refer to previous state, without the need to do any record.